# Getting Response size exceeded 15MB organization limit on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, governorlimits

I am getting the Response size exceeded 15MB organization limit error when i clicked a button from VF page which is not able to trace in debug logs
and the debug log as follows:

```
Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 550 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

07:56:46.406 (3406940521)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
```

Comment: Post some more information like what kind of operation is happening upon clicking the button and the different approaches you have tried to avoid hitting the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Debug logs don't show this limit. This limit is related to the content rendered on the visualforce page when you click on the `button` (or can be other reason). When you click the command button, the page content is becoming larger than 15 MB. Try to identify what your page is showing.

Debug logs shows limits for **Apex Execution** and **System Logs**, not Organization limits for Visualforce pages (View Level).

Explaination of this limit is given here as well: [Visualforce Response Size Exceeded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/visualforce-response-size-exceeded)