# How does the standard set controller manage state?

Tags: apex, standardsetcontroller

I have a VF datatable, where the user needs to update some fields on each record, and there can be thousands (though less than 10k). I learned that I could do that with the StandardSetController, and it worked great! Except I don't know how it manages the state so well. I think the connection is between the getQueryLocator, setting the Pagesize and the pagination. Can someone break it down for me?

```
 setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT 
      Id, Name, Cf1__c, Cf2__c, Cf3__c,Cf4__c, Cf__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE 
    LIMIT 10000
  ])); 

  setCon.setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE);
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are asking.

Comment: Not a direct answer but will give you so good reading on the internal view state http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-to-reduce-a-large-internal-view-state-what-is-in-the-internal-view-state/4721#4721