How do I turn a base64Encoded PDF file into an open PDF with apex
We are trying to make an integration app for salesforce. The flow is:

User Clicks a button
Salesforce sends data to our system
Our system returns a PDF document
That PDF gets displayed for the user in some meaningful way

My Apex Code (the relevant bits)
public class POCApexClass {
    public Blob pdfContent{get;set;}
    public Blob pdfContent2{get;set;}
    public string pdfContentBase64{get;set;}
    public void CommunicationRequestDemoPDF(){
        OutputDocument doc = GetDoc();
        pdfContentBase64 =  doc.outputBase64;
        pdfContent = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pdfContentBase64);
        pdfContent2 = Blob.toPDF(pdfContentBase64);
    }
}

If there's apex code that will just open the file in the browser or another app or something that would be perfect. It does seem like I might need to use visualForce code for that? I've tried several approaches there.
<apex:page controller="POCApexClass" action="{!CommunicationRequestDemoPDF}">
    <apex:form >
        Sample PDF
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel >  
        <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdfContentBase64}"></object>
        <!-- 
        <iframe src="/apex/RenderPDFPage?base64String={!pdfContentBase64}" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <apex:outputText value="{!pdfContent2}" escape="false"/>
        <script>
            window.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdfContentBase64}";
        </script>
        -->
    </apex:outputPanel>   
</apex:page>

They all spit out the error: Maximum view state size limit (170KB) exceeded.  Actual view state size for this page was 192.954KB
Is there any way to boost the frame size? or a way for it to display in a new window? or just get downloaded and opened like a normal PDF?
Thanks for the help
UPDATE
Turns out the lines
        pdfContent = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pdfContentBase64);
        pdfContent2 = Blob.toPDF(pdfContentBase64);

Are causing the issue, I can't have blobs I guess? Removing them lets the  tag do stuff. It lets me download the PDF. It doesn't let me view it in browser, or let me download it automatically though - I'm still stumped on that point. This is the view and it's not the most professional looking thing ever. Ignore the 'link test' button, that's me exploring other routes.


Have you had a look at this question?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-to-reduce-a-large-internal-view-state-what-is-in-the-internal-view-state

I have now @NickC , doesn't seem like we have the same problem - turns out instantiating pdfContent or pdfContent2 are causing the issue, removing both lines lets my app do stuff at least. I'll update the post now
